# Data mismatch while dumping array in csv file

Tags: php, arrays

I have 7 array fetched by mysql and its working correctly each array have exactly 9 rows which are city_names but one of the array has only 7 rows since two values on the results where null . This causes confunsion while dumping file in csv. I use the below code. Is there any way to check it by city name without using foreach for eact array ?

```
        for($i=0 ; $i <= $count-2 ; $i++)
        {
            $data[] = $all_restaurants_opr_no_temp_off[$i]['city_name'];

            $data[] = $all_restaurants_opr[$i]['total'];


            $data[] = $all_restaurants_opr_no_temp_off[$i]['total'];



            $data[] = $restaurants_opr_temp_off[$i]['total'];

                $data[] = $restaurants_opr_operations_closed[$i]['total'];

                $data[] = $restaurants_opr_automated[$i]['total'];

                $data[] = $restaurants_opr_automated_working[$i]['total'];

                $data[] = $restaurants_opr_online_payment[$i]['total'];

                $data[] = $restaurants_opr_online_payment_with_tempoff[$i]['total'];

                $data[] = $restaurants_opr_atleast_one_order[$i]['total'];

            fputcsv($fp, $data,",");
            unset($data);
            }


Array 1:
array(9) {
   [0]=>
  array(2) {
    ["city_name"]=>
    string(9) "Bangalore"
    ["total"]=>
    string(3) "687"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(2) {
    ["city_name"]=>
    string(9) "Hyderabad"
    ["total"]=>
    string(2) "16"
  }
  [2]=>
  array(2) {
    ["city_name"]=>
    string(6) "Mumbai"
    ["total"]=>
    string(3) "568"
  }
  [3]=>
  array(2) {
    ["city_name"]=>
    string(7) "Chennai"
    ["total"]=>
    string(3) "139"
  }
  [4]=>
  array(2) {
    ["city_name"]=>
    string(4) "Pune"
    ["total"]=>
    string(3) "232"
  }
  [5]=>
  array(2) {
    ["city_name"]=>
    string(9) "Ghaziabad"
    ["total"]=>
    string(2) "57"
  }
  [6]=>
  array(2) {
    ["city_name"]=>
    string(5) "Noida"
    ["total"]=>
    string(2) "77"
  }
  [7]=>
  array(2) {
    ["city_name"]=>
    string(9) "Faridabad"
    ["total"]=>
    string(1) "4"
  }
  [8]=>
  array(2) {
    ["city_name"]=>
    string(7) "Gurgaon"
    ["total"]=>
    string(3) "113"
  }
}
Array 2:
array(9) {
  [0]=>
  array(2) {
    ["city_name"]=>
    string(9) "Bangalore"
    ["total"]=>
    string(3) "674"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(2) {
    ["city_name"]=>
    string(9) "Hyderabad"
    ["total"]=>
    string(2) "16"
  }
  [2]=>
  array(2) {
    ["city_name"]=>
    string(6) "Mumbai"
    ["total"]=>
    string(3) "547"
  }
  [3]=>
  array(2) {
    ["city_name"]=>
    string(7) "Chennai"
    ["total"]=>
    string(3) "135"
  }
  [4]=>
  array(2) {
    ["city_name"]=>
    string(4) "Pune"
    ["total"]=>
    string(3) "202"
  }
  [5]=>
  array(2) {
    ["city_name"]=>
    string(9) "Ghaziabad"
    ["total"]=>
    string(2) "56"
  }
  [6]=>
  array(2) {
    ["city_name"]=>
    string(5) "Noida"
    ["total"]=>
    string(2) "77"
  }
  [7]=>
  array(2) {
    ["city_name"]=>
    string(9) "Faridabad"
    ["total"]=>
    string(1) "4"
  }
  [8]=>
  array(2) {
    ["city_name"]=>
    string(7) "Gurgaon"
    ["total"]=>
    string(3) "111"
  }
}
Array 3:(Problem is here)
array(6) {
  [0]=>
  array(2) {
    ["city_name"]=>
    string(9) "Bangalore"
    ["total"]=>
    string(2) "13"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(2) {
    ["city_name"]=>
    string(6) "Mumbai"
    ["total"]=>
    string(2) "21"
  }
  [2]=>
  array(2) {
    ["city_name"]=>
    string(7) "Chennai"
    ["total"]=>
    string(1) "4"
  }
  [3]=>
  array(2) {
    ["city_name"]=>
    string(4) "Pune"
    ["total"]=>
    string(2) "30"
  }
  [4]=>
  array(2) {
    ["city_name"]=>
    string(9) "Ghaziabad"
    ["total"]=>
    string(1) "1"
  }
  [5]=>
  array(2) {
    ["city_name"]=>
    string(7) "Gurgaon"
    ["total"]=>
    string(1) "2"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand the question 100%, but perhaps you can test each value if it is null and put a default value there if it is, for example, for this row, you could use this above your for loop:

```
foreach($badArray as $b){
  $reformattedArray[$b['city_name']] = $b['total'];
}
```

then replace the bad array line with this in your for loop

```
data[] = is_null($reformattedArray[$all_restaurants_opr_no_temp_off[$i]['city_name']]) ? 'Default' : $reformattedArray[$all_restaurants_opr_no_temp_off[$i]['city_name']];
```

Comment: i can do that . But city wise it will be mismatcching since i use for loop?

Comment: If you can somehow show the underlying data issue here it would help, ie the error in the spreadsheet data, also how are those different arrays created?

Comment: included the arrays please check/

Comment: There are a number of ways to do this, but will involve looping through and changing the index of the arrays, it might be better if you created the arrays in a different way when you selected the data, how are the arrays being created?

Comment: fetched from mysql result!!

Comment: I exactly dont want to loop through every array ? It will be more complex!!

Comment: I gave you an alternative by amending my answer, but the real answer here is you need to do a better job selecting and joining your data in MySQL